# How to catch global exceptions in the version of .NET Core 2.1

Tags: c#, .net-core-2.1

The old project that the company is maintaining is using .NET Core 2.1. `AddHostedService` is written in the program file to register the background service. Now some background services throw unhandled exceptions that cause the program to crash.

Is there any way to capture it globally? So this unhandled exception, ensure that the program does not crash.

I tried to register `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.FirstChanceException` globally. Although the exception was caught, the program still crashed.

Comment: How many services do you have? Can't you just add a try/catch inside `ExecuteAsync`?

Comment: There are almost 30 of them, and now there is no way to guarantee that each background service has done exception handling, and there is no way to guarantee that if new background services are added later, exception handling will also be done, so I would like to ask if there is a comprehensive global exception capture

Comment: You still can't trust the state of the system when an exception goes unhandled like that.